# mongodb sort/query on calculated value aggregation-framework?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with relations to other collections, I want to select a for the user most relevant selection of records as follows:

First records that have this.some_collection_id == 'someid' && this.another_collection_id == 'another_id'
then records that have this.some_collection_id == 'someid'
then records that have this.another_collection_id == 'another_id'
then other records

**example**: Lets say the main collection is stories, and each story has an 'interest_group' and a 'location'. All users have a 'primary interest group' and a 'location'. I'd like to query the top 100 most interesting stories for a specific user, stories with the same interest group & location should weigh 5, same interest group only 3, same location only 2 and the rest 1.

I'd like to award these points during the query so that I can sort the stories collection based on these points and return the top 100.

So I can do 4 separate queries and merge the results client side (not so pretty) or I can try to get the collection in the right order.

So far I have come up with the following:

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    var score = 1;
    if (this.some_id == "#{some_id}") {
      score = score + 3
    }
    if (this.another_id == "#{another_id}") {
      score = score + 2
    }

    emit(this._id, { _id: this._id, score: score });
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    return values;
  }
}

MyCollection.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
```

This will correctly return the entire collection of records with a score attached, however I cannot sort on the score so I will have to do that client side (also ugly as I would only need the top 100 records or so)

Is there a way to do this differently? I have also checked out the aggregation framework but I dont see how this will solve this particular query.

Comment: Well the question is a bit vauge, which is the largest reason no-one has touched it. Can you at least edit to show some sample documents ( just a few ) and what should be matching to a desired result. That would help the understanding immensely.

Comment: Thanks, let me try to add some relevant data

Comment: Please do. I think I get your gist, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: Was actually hoping for some real data with values as opposed yo what you just added. But the following is at least the analog to the code you have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here as mentioned does not really explain the logic here as well as it should, but if I do catch your general meaning then this should be pretty much the analog of the above, with the extra enhancements you want also:

```
MyCollection.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project" => {
        "score" => {
            "$add" => [
                { "$cond" => [
                    { "$or" => [
                        { "$eq" => [ "$some_id" => some_id_var1 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$some_id" => some_id_var2 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$some_id" => some_id_var3 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$some_id" => some_id_var4 ] }
                    ]},
                    3,
                    0
                ]},
                { "$cond" => [
                    { "$or" => [
                        { "$eq" => [ "$another_id" => another_id_var1 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$another_id" => another_id_var2 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$another_id" => another_id_var3 ] },
                        { "$eq" => [ "$another_id" => another_id_var4 ] }
                    ]},
                    2,
                    0
                ]},
                1
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort" => { "score" => -1 } },
    { "$limit" => 100 }
])
```

Essentially this is exactly the same thing in that for both "some_id" and "another_id" fields are being compared against some variable input to see if they match and return a score. The addition I did here is you mention *"4 queries"*, so that sounds like variable changes. This should just be accomodated with an [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) condition instead in both cases. If you are really only comparing one value in each case, then just remove the wrapping `$or`.

The [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator itself is the "if/then/else" ternary operation. So the first argument is "if" and the next arguments are what returns on `true/false` respectively. In this case your attribuited score or `0`.

Then wrapping that all up with [**`add`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) produces the "total score" for each document, with the same logic you are using.

Also note that [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) requires you to output all of the fields you want in the result "explicitly". Your mapReduce does nothing but `_id` and `score` so I am just doing the same here. But you can add other fields as needed. The `_id` is of course always implicit unless specified otherwise, such as `"_id" => 0`.

All that is left are the [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on the "score" value, and the [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) for the total results after sorting. Which are both things that mapReduce cannot do.

That is basically adding weights based on the matched properties and then "sorting" and "limiting" the results to the top scores. Also note that as a "data structure", variables in the aggregation pipelines you want to use are just native code, and don't need the "stringify" treatment you are doing with mapReduce.

Comment: Re-reading the question I must say I've expressed myself better in the past :) Thanks for reading though it and explaining how to use the aggregation framework like this. I've been able to get a proof of concept query working